# Way to wrap functionality with in delegate declaration

Tags: c#, multithreading

I really dislike having to create delegates to give threads functionality. If I was currently using Method A to do work but then realized that it would be better off being run in a thread, now I have to create a delegate and another method to actually run the thread. So now I have Method A starting thread which then works by delegating to Method B.

**My Question is:**
**Can I wrap functionality within a thread declaration itself?**

Something like

```
System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(
                new delegate()
                {
            SqlConnection Connection = Helpers.ConnectionHelper.CreateConnection();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("MarkNotificationRead", Connection);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = this.id;

            Connection.Open();

            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            catch 
            {

            }

            Connection.Close();
                });
```

I've seen something like this done before somewhere but can't find the example anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is very close, just minor syntactic changes - get rid of the `new`, and the `()`:

```
System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(
            delegate
            {
        SqlConnection Connection = Helpers.ConnectionHelper.CreateConnection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("MarkNotificationRead", Connection);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = this.id;

        Connection.Open();

        try
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        catch 
        {

        }

        Connection.Close();
            }));
```

An alternative is to use lambda syntax, in which you can get rid of the `ThreadStart` call:

```
System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(
            () =>
            {
                  ...
            });
```

Comment: :D Thank you. Very simple solution!